# creating index using elastic4s is throwing exception about not finding ScalaObjectMapper

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am trying to create an index using elastic4s frame work in Elasticsearch

here is my code

```
elasticsearchClient.execute {
                createIndex(indexName).mapping(
                    properties(
                        dateField("Field_1"),
                        keywordField("Field_2"),
                        keywordField("Field_3"),
                        keywordField("Field_4"),
                        keywordField("Field_4"),
                        doubleField("Field_5"),
                        keywordField("Field_6")
                    )
                )
            }
```

Throws the exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper
```

Am I missing something? Can I give case class and elastic4s can create an index?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the jackson version to 2.14.2. it works.
elastic4s version is 7.17.4